# Microsoft Word Library reference - interference in code

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I'm trying to create Microsoft Word documents from my context menu on form, but problem is that when I add reference and Imports statement for Microsoft Word, my form code get's errors. Looks like certain synthax means something else when referencing Word Library. So I need either replacement for these synthaxes or a suggestion of how I could still use Word reference without changing anything in code (I tried Imports statements in module or new class, but that doesn't work I guess). Here are my lines that get's errors:

```
Dim ptLowerLeft As New Point(-62, btnSender.Height) 'A code for setting position of Listview under button - "Point" is what gets error

 ListView1.View = View.Details 'Changing view of my Listview - "Details" get's error : "Details is not a member of View (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.View)
```

Reference is Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library, with Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word statement in my form.

What to do ?

Comment: What type of object is "View" in View.Details? It's picking up a member called Details from Interop, if you fully qualify View.Details you will not get that problem.

Comment: Its the `System.Windows.Forms.View` enum  @soohoonigan

Comment: @soohoonigan, thanks for info. Yes It's system.windows.forms.view. Anyway, what I did now is that I changed "Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" to just "Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop" and everything works, no error and Word document gets created. Am I about to experience issues somewhere else If I leave It like this ?

Comment: I don't know, that's hard to guess because that's totally dependent on what imports the entire solution is using, and whether any of those imports just so happen to have members that share the same name as another import's member. But generally, those can always be solved by changing the import statement like you did, or fully qualifying the member (i.e. Listview would become System.Windows.Forms.ListView)

Comment: @soohoonigan, thanks. I'll follow this rules in future, good to know. My problem is solved, you can post an answer If you like, to close this thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the types `Point` and `View` exist both in the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` and in the `System.Windows.Forms` or in the `System.Drawing` namespace. If all of these namespaces are imported the compiler can no longer uniquely identify the type you want to use in your code.

There are two ways to resolve this conflict:

- Don't import one of the namespace and use the fully qualified name. In your case, you could omit the import of the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` namespace and then use the full type name when using the interop types.

  ```
  Imports System.Drawing
  Imports System.Windows.Forms

  ' in your code you can address Word types using the fully-qualified name:
  Dim app as New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
  Dim doc as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = app.Documents.Add()
  ```
- The first option can get messy because you will always have to use the fully qualified type names everywhere. This can be simplified by using a namespace alias:

  ```
  Imports System.Drawing
  Imports System.Windows.Forms
  Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

  ' in your code you can address Word types using the alias:
  Dim app as New Word.Application
  Dim doc as Word.Document = app.Documents.Add()
  ```

Comment: thanks , very useful too. I like your second suggestion, didn't knew I could reference like this.